# Python - What does it mean to return a function object?

Tags: python, oop, decorator

I'm trying to get my head around Decorators in Python. I've got a handle on what they are for from various answers [[ex]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/how-to-make-a-chain-of-function-decorators) on SO: to run code before and/or after a decorated function without modifying the function itself. That said, I'm having trouble understanding what it means to return a function object.

What is the difference between returning the *return value* of a function and returning the *function object*? I get that a reference to the function itself is returned, but what is the utility of this behavior?

I didn't use the `@Decorator` syntax below as I'm still learning that.

For example:

```
def some_func():
    print('returning 1')
    return 1
def Decorator(func):
    def Wrapper():
        print('doing something first')
        val = func()
        print('doing something after')
        return val
    return Wrapper
Decorated_func = Decorator(some_func)
Decorated_func()
```

Stepping through this in PythonTutor: calling Decorated_func() shows that `Wrapper` has a return value of `1` and `Decorator` has a return value of `Wrapper`. Does that mean that `Decorator` *actually* has a return value of `1` when `Decorated_func()` is called? I would have thought that the syntax for that behavior would be (within `Decorator`) `return Wrapper()`. What is the point of returning a function object?

Comment: A function is just an object, like a list or an int. It serves the same purpose as returning any other object from a function.

Comment: It seems that you're really asking "Why are higher order functions useful?"

Comment: If you return `Wrapper()` then `Decorated_func == 1` and it will not be a function... try doing that and then see what happens when you try to use `Decorated_func` as a function

Comment: @Brian yes, and the OP even provides an example of where it would be useful.

Comment: And **no**, that does **not mean** that `Decorator` actually has a return value of `1`, is has a return value of the wrapper function you created inside `Decorator`

Comment: Don’t be distracted by the complexity of implementing decorators - a function object Returned by a decorator can be called with parameters and return results derived from those parameters, whereas a value can’t because it’s, err, a value.

Comment: @barny a function *is a value*. there is no distinction between "values and functions", functions are first-class objects, just like any other value.

Comment: Yeah but in the OP’s example a value might be an integer, or a string, or a list - a function object is callable with parameters

Comment: Thank you all. Quite illuminating, it's making more sense now. @Brian, yes it seems that is my actual question! I'll keep reading.  If I'm getting it, returning a function allows you to call the function *with parameters*.

Answer (score 1):

When you return a function, the caller can call it multiple times with different arguments, and it can calculate a different result each time.

If you return the result of calling the function, you're just returning that one value, it will never change. And since it's not a function, you can't call it with different arguments.

Here's a simpler example:

```
def adder(x):
    def add_x(y):
        return x + y
    return add_x

add_1 = adder(1)
add_3 = adder(3)
print(add_1(10)) # prints 11
print(add_1(20)) # prints 21
print(add_3(10)) # prints 13
```

If you changed it to something like `return add_x(5)` then `adder(1)` would simply return `6`, not a function that you can call with different arguments.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's clarify your nice, focused question:

> Does that mean that Decorator actually has a return value of 1 when Decorated_func() is called?

No.  `Decorator` is a configuration tool.  You feed it a function object.  `Decorator` inserts that function object into its hidden template (`Wrapper`), and then returns that customized `Wrapper` as a new function.  That customized function is the return value of `Decorator`.

Calling that wrapper does *not* alter how `Decorator` operates.  Note that this is *not* a call to `Decorator`.  `Decorator` made a customized version of wrapper -- *that* is what has a value of `1`.  `Decorator` is still its original self, a customization factory waiting for someone to insert some other function.

Answer (score 0):

Returning a function allows you a "call in 2 steps". For example, from the same base function, you could create as many functions as you want.

```py
def testDecorator(x):
    print(f'I am {x}')
    return x * 2

def printA(func):
    def wrapper(x):
       print('I am the decorator A opening')
       result = func(x)
       print('I am the decorator A ending')
       return result
    return wrapper

def printB(func):
    def wrapper(x):
       print('I am the decorator B opening')
       result = func(x)
       print('I am the decorator B ending')
       return result
    return wrapper

testA = printA(testDecorator)
testB = printB(testDecorator)
```

```
>>> testA(5)
I am the decorator A opening
I am 5
I am the decorator A ending
10
>>> testB(5)
I am the decorator B opening
I am 5
I am the decorator B ending
10
```